# Finding exact values of $A$ and $B$ from exponential point on graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function

I am faced with a problem that I cannot seem to solve. Here it is:

> The graph $y = a^x + b$ is shown below, find the EXACT values of $a$ and $b$.

The graph is an exponential graph, it has a $y$-intercept at $(0,-4)$ and it also labels a point at $(2,5)$ in quadrant $1$.

Any help would be great, Thank you all!

Comment: Plug in the pairs you have into their positions in the formula and get two equations each relating $a,b$. Solve those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations obtained by plugging in $(x,y)=(0,-4)$ is $-4=a^0+b=1+b$ (since $a^0=1$). This gives that $b=-5$. When the other point $(2,5)$ is plugged into the now updated $y=a^x-5$ it gives $5=a^2-5$ which is $a^2=10$. Usually the base of an exponential function is taken to be positive, so that the function is defined for all real $x$. If that is your convention, $a=\sqrt{10}$ is the only choice.

(Otherwise if one is content with using a negative base and restricting to only certain rational exponents, one could choose $-\sqrt{10}$ for $a$, but this causes problems when raised to real variable $x$...)

So this gives $y=(\sqrt{10})^x-5$ which may be rewritten to avoid the squareroot sign as $y=10^{x/2}-5.$

Check: at $x=0$ we get $y=10^0-5=-4$, and at $x=2$ it is $y=10^{2/2}-5=10-5=5.$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand how to approach these problems now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Each point gives you one equation. Using the given points, you have two equations for $a,b$. As all powers of $a$ are even, you can define $z=a^2$. I find two positive solutions, neither with a nice expression.